# Estimate weights given a weighted geometric median

Tags: median, weighted-data, geometry, geometric-mean

#### Problem 1

Given a set of points and their weighted geometric median, find the weights associated with each point.

For instance, given the points `((1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1))` and a weighted geometric median at `(2.447, 1.450)`, find the weights. The geometric median (non-weighted) is in green and the ground truth weighted median is in red. We need to find the weights of each point that result in the weighted geometric median.

[image: Problem 1 image]

Note that I am using `compute_geometric_median` but other algorithms are also available, e.g. from [ArcGIS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/h-how-median-center-spatial-statistics-works.htm).

```py
from geom_median.numpy import compute_geometric_median  # NumPy API
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array(((1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1)))
out = compute_geometric_median(points)
current_median = out.median.round(3)

# Checking the solution
ground_truth_median = np.array((2.447, 1.450))
weights_to_find = (1.2, 1.5, 1.4, 3.3)
out_check = compute_geometric_median(points, weights_to_find)
ground_truth_median_check = out_check.median.round(3)
np.equal(ground_truth_median_check, ground_truth_median).all() # outputs True

# to reproduce the image
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 3))
axes.plot(current_median[0], current_median[1], marker='o', color='green')
axes.plot(ground_truth_median[0], ground_truth_median[1], marker='x', color='red')
for x, y in points:
    axes.plot(x, y, marker='o', color='blue')
```

#### Problem 2

Given a set of points with weights and their ground truth weighted geometric median, find the corrected set of weights which **a**) minimizes absolute differences between the original weight and the corrected weight per point (i.e. it's better to increase the weight of two points by 0.2 each instead of increasing the weight of one of them by 0.4), and **b**) minimizes the distance between the ground truth weighted geometric median and the newly calculated one.

For this one, I am not even sure how to begin. Imagine we start  from a random position as in the above example, although this time the starting weights are not 1s, but:

```py
starting_weights= (1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.5)
```

How would we find an algorithm that still gives us back the ground truth weights, i.e. `(1.2, 1.5, 1.4, 3.3)` and fulfils the above 2 criteria **a** and **b**.

Comment: The problem usually has infinitely many solutions. With $n$ points, the weight vectors $w$ form the $n-1$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ a manifold $M^{n-1}$ of dimension $n-1.$ The w.g.m is a point in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Thus, the w.g.m is a function $\operatorname{wgm}:M^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}^2.$ Although not necessarily continuous everywhere, it will be continuous in most of $M^{n-1},$ and so generically the inverse image $\operatorname{wgm}^{-1}(x)$ of a point $x$ in the image of $\operatorname{wgm}$ includes a manifold of dimension $n-1-2.$ For $n\ge 4,$ that comprises infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @whuber As neither a mathematician, nor a statistician, it's a bit tricky for me to follow the explanation (still very useful!), though I easily reach the same conclusion thinking about this more conceptually. I'd be perfectly happy to consider imposing further restrictions on the possible solutions -- any generic advice on what those might look like? E.g.: a simple brute force approach (for Problem 2): vary all weights randomly around the starting weight X times and get the best solution. Might not be optimal but the greater the X, the more likely it is to approximate an optimal solution.

Comment: There is no prospect of any "optimal solution" until you can quantify for us what would make one solution better than another.